# MySql how to optimize this select by date query to use an index?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 1M records in it, with several keys; customer name and invoice date, being two of the keys.
[image]

I then have a query that I use to retrieve and group data. When I run explain on the query, it seems like it's not using my invoice date index. How do I optimize it?

[image]

The following is the query:

```
 SELECT 
  business_unit as 'Service Center',
  fixed_customer_name AS 'Customer',
  trade as 'Trade (system)',
  fixed_trade as 'Trade',
  state as 'State',
  Last_day(invoice_date) as 'Month Ending',
  SUM(revenue) AS 'Revenue',
  (SUM(revenue) - SUM(cogs)) AS 'GP',
  COUNT(fixed_customer_name) as 'Ticket Count',
  fixed_job_type AS 'Type'

FROM Invoice_new

WHERE 
  invoice_date >= '2018-01-01'

GROUP BY
  business_unit,
  fixed_customer_name,
  trade,
  fixed_trade,
  state,
  fixed_job_type,
  Last_day(invoice_date)

Order by
  invoice_date,
  fixed_customer_name,
  fixed_trade
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by so many fields?  The `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are what's slowing the query down.

Comment: An index can improve the performance of your query if the percentage of rows the filtering predicate `invoice_date >= '2018-01-01'` is selecting is low; at most 5%, ideally 0.5% or less. The questions is, what percentage of the rows is that condition [in average] selecting?

Comment: @TheImpaler that makes sense. Thanks for pointing it out. This is selecting more than half of the database, then compresses the output by grouping the data. So I guess I can't really make a super fast select of groups when querying such a large subset of data?

Comment: You can improve the speed marginally by using a covering index, if the number of columns you are selecting is far less than the total number of columns of the table.